# You are not authorized to view this page

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

tengo problemas subiendo archivos war a tomcat me sale algo como esto

```
403 Access Denied
You are not authorized to view this page.

By default the Manager is only accessible from a browser running on the same machine as Tomcat. If you wish to modify this restriction, you'll need to edit the Manager's context.xml file.
```

Y tengo todo bien según yo relacionado con los permisos

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>

<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

Qué creen que pueda ser? 
Con anterioridad podia subir sin problema pero ahora ya no me deja, intenté volviendo a instalar tomcat y sigue igual